# Translating a math formula to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math

I'm trying to translate this math formula to JS:

[image: this piece of formula]

I tried to use `tan^-1` for the first part but got an error.

Comment: There a math functions in javascript - Math.sin(), Math.tan(), etc.  Take a look at W3Schools.com

Comment: @toni : I know, but what's that "-1" is for ? Math.pow() you mean the res is something like this : tan( 2 L sin(α) ) / ( 2 L cos(α) + w sin(α) )

Comment: It's referring to the inverse tangent. https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-inverse-sin-cos-tan.html

Comment: You can use the `Math.atan()' function to get the arctan otherwise known as the inverse tangent. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_atan.asp

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math

Comment: @TimHunter: thanks!!!! =) , so at the end the res is something like this :
Math.atan( 2*L*Math.sin(α) ) / ( 2*L*Math.cos(α) + w*Math.sin(α) ) ???? right ?

Comment: no because what is `LMath`? JS Engine does not realize what that is. You need to specify the multiplication.

Comment: Don't forget the * between L and the Math functions. It'd be `2*L*Math.sin(a)` ect....

Comment: @TimHunter :
I know, in the comments sometimes * character remove when I posting,
Thank you so much =)

Comment: You can usually avoid that by surrounding the piece of code with the backquote ` symbol just left of your 1 key. This tells the page to render it as a code block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
function phi_i (l, w, phi) {
   // Check and set defaults for the parameters l, w and phi in case the are not set properly ...
   var arg = 2 * l * Math.sin(phi) / ( 2 * l * Math.cos(phi) - w * Math.sin(phi) );
   return Math.atan(arg);
}
```